# Fuzzy scoring top N in Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to build a `dataframe` of word and `fuzzywuzzy` score, and take top 5.

For example I have test word `test = "kuku"`

My bag of words are:

```
words = ["tutu", "pupu", "lulu", "kuko", "dfvfd", "wwwer"]
```

I have done the following so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

test = "kuku"
[print(i, fuzz.ratio(i, test)) for i in words]
```

But I want to be able to sort and take top N by score.

Please advise what is the best practice to solve such issue?

Comment: There are specific functions within the `fuzzywuzzy` library, such as `process.extractBests`, that do what you're looking for.

Comment: @Andy please provide an example

Comment: `from fuzzywuzzy import process`; `process.extractBests(test, words, limit=N)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process.extract() of Fuzzywuzzy returns the list of words in reverse sorted order. The first match will be the best one.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 
from fuzzywuzzy import process 

query = 'sat'
choices = ['slate', 'saturn', 'satellite', 'sat', 'shore']  
print(f"top 3: {process.extract(query, choices)[:3]}")
```